# Issues with pushing variables directly on to stack

Tags: assembly, stack

My current code works, and is as follows:

```
movzx  ecx, var1
lea    eax, var2

push eax             
push ecx             

call func1

//...
```

and func1 is:

```
push ebp           
mov ebp, esp       

mov ecx, [ebp + 8] 
mov eax, [ebp + 12]

push edi           
push ecx           

not byte ptr[eax] 

//...
```

However, I wish to push the address of var2 directly, along with simply pushing the value of var1 like so, but I'm having trouble figuring out how:

```
push var1            
push var2 //address of)

call func1
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the address of a register value.

However, there are two things you can do:

If the value is in the psuedo-register `var2` and is created through the operation of *your* program (i.e, isn't a syscall return register, etc.), you could simply do the following instead of `mov var2, [avar2]`

```
mov var2, avar2
```

If that doesn't suit you, you can push `var2` to the stack and get the address from `esp`, e.g

```
push var2
lea avar2, [esp-4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the byte variable `var1` has a DWORD space(4-bytes) in memory and is zero extended, you could just `PUSH` it. The `LEA` of `var2'` could be replaced if the address of `var2` is at a constant address in the `.data` segment. Like this:

```
push var1
push offset var2            
call func1
```

Under these conditions your requirements would be easily satisfiable.

Comment: On `80186` and onward `PUSH` can take an immediate operand.

Comment: Thanks. However, var1 is a char, what change would that make to the above? Also, I am not sure what you mean by 'offset' as that is an invalid operand.

Answer (score 0):

With compiler EMU8086 you can do it. Next is your code with some changes (I'm using 16 bit registers, that's why BP+4 and BP+6) :

```
.stack 100h
.data  
var1 dw 25              ;VAR1 = 25.
var2 dw 800             ;VAR2 = 800.
.code
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

  push var1             ;PUSH 25.
  push offset var2      ;PUSH ADDRESS OF 800.
  call func1

  mov  ax, 4c00h 
  int  21h              ;FINISH.

func1 proc
  push bp
  mov  bp, sp
  mov  si, [ bp + 4 ]   ;POP ADDRESS OF 800.
  mov  ax, [ bp + 6 ]   ;POP 25.  

  not  [ byte ptr si ]  ;CX CANNOT BE USED AS POINTER.

  pop  bp
  ret
func1 endp
```

The address of 800 is extracted into SI instead of CX because CX cannot be used to point to the address.

Remember that things in stack are stored upside down : 25 is pushed first then the address of 800, that's why the address is in position BP+4 and 25 in BP+6.